# Nginx : What is possible downtime for switchover for Active-Passive clustering

Tags: nginx, failover

I understand OpenSource NginX does provide Active-Passive clustering of multiple Nginx web servers. For Active-Active, Nginx Plus required which is paid.

How much is switchover time in case of Active-Passive configuration in Open Source version ?

Answer (score 1):

You would use something like keepalived to setup floating IP’s between two NGINX servers.

The keepalived configuration can be active-active if you split the IP addresses between the two hosts and configure two VRRP instances.

Or you can go active-passive if you put all the IP addresses on a single host and only configure one VRRP instance.

Each NGINX server would have the same configuration and you can setup a script to copy the config files between the servers.

The keepalived failover itself is really fast. I lose a single ping when doing a failover as the ARP cache on my core switch updates with the new MAC address for the IP address.

Hope this helps!